# UML - Class inheritance, what do you inherit?

Tags: uml

Does inheritance in UML indicate just inheriting the attributes/operations, or also the links/associations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really going to depend on how the links/associations are declared: public, private or protected. Links and associations are commonly implemented using properties so any links/associations implemented as private would not be inherited however protected or public would be inherited.

Comment: I did not know associations can have different scopes. Can you provide any links for more info on this? Thanks

Comment: @amax: It's referred to as visibility, you can find some details on good old Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Visibility)

Answer (score 0):

I also found this useful for generalization:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cgeneral.html

"You can add generalization relationships to capture attributes, operations, and relationships in a parent model element and then reuse them in one or more child model elements."

Answer (score 0):

A good test would be to detect inheritances by the UML reverse engineering into a class diagram from an existing code. Thea java inheritance code is explained at: http://www.java.happycodings.com/Learning/code26.html

Attributes are usually used for associations detections.
Dependencies are coming from both inheritance and association as well as other code.